# Why is this returning an extra none?

Tags: python

```
def hotel_cost(nights):
    return nights * 140

bill = hotel_cost(5)

def add_monthly_interest(balance):
    return balance * (1 + (0.15 / 12))

def make_payment(payment, balance): 
    new_balance2 = balance - payment
    new_balance = add_monthly_interest(new_balance2)
    print "You still owe: " + str(new_balance)

make_payment(100,bill)
```

Why does this return

```
You still owe: 607.5
None
```

?

Comment: How are you running the program?

Comment: It doesn't return that. It returns `None`, because that's what any function returns if you don't have a `return` statement. And it prints out "You still owe: 607.5", because that's what's in your `print` statement. My guess is you're running inside an IDE or other interactive session that's printing out the return value of each statement. So, your code prints "You still owe: 607.5", and then your interactive interpreter prints "None".

Comment: I literally started learning a few days ago, and I'm running it in code academy.  So it is using their interpreter.  Maybe its a problem on their end?

Comment: What version are you using? This does not return 'None' in 2.7.3

Comment: Of course it returns `None`. What else could `make_payment(100, bill)` return? There are no `return` statements anywhere in `make_payment`, so, if it returns (doesn't `raise` or `_exit` or anything), it will return `None`.

Comment: It's not a problem on their end.  It's normal, expected behavior that you happen to not understand yet.  There is a difference between what a function **prints** and what a function **returns**.  See @abarnert's answer.

Comment: @user2368136: That isn't really a _problem_. It's a little different from the standard interpreter, in that it prints the value of _any_ expression, instead of printing the value of any expression _that doesn't evaluate to `None`_. But either way, you have to learn to distinguish `print` output from interpreter output.

Answer (score 7):

It doesn't return that. It returns `None`, because that's what any function returns if you don't have a return statement.

Meanwhile, it prints out "You still owe: 607.5", because that's what's in your print statement.

(By "it" here, I'm assuming you're referring to the function call `make_payment(100, bill)`.)

My guess is you're running inside an IDE or other interactive session that's printing out the return value of each statement. So, your code prints "You still owe: 607.5", and then your interactive interpreter prints "None".

The default `python` interactive interpreter (like `ipython` and `bpython` and many others) will swallow up `None` returns instead of printing them out. Whichever one you're using presumably doesn't do that.

Comment: I don't mean to sound stupid, but is there any way to fix that through the inteactive IDE that that I am using?  I want to set the course as complete online.  If not I'm just going to move on.

Comment: Also, thanks for your answer, it explains the issue very well.

Comment: @user2368136: What do you mean by "fix"? You don't want the interactive interpreter to stop being interactive; that would make it useless. If they have a way to write a script and run it, instead of working within their interactive interpreter, you probably want to do that for your final testing. (I have no idea if they have such a thing, and it's probably more a question for CodeAcademy than for SO, but maybe someone here knows.)

Comment: I feel like I'm not really getting it.  Where did I tell it to do anything other than  print "You still owe: " + str(new_balance)

Comment: Well I guess since I didn't tell it to return something, just to print something, and if it doesn't return anything, then the interpreter makes it return none, but how do I make it have no return?

Comment: @user2368136: In Python, "have no return" means exactly the same thing as "return `None`". Or, put a different way, if you don't tell it what to return (whether by writing a `return` statement without a value, or just by letting it fall off the end of the function with no `return` statement), it returns `None`. So, you're already doing the right thing.

Comment: abarnert is 100% correct. but think of it like this:

EVERY FUNCTION RETURNS SOMETHING

if you do not specifically tell it, its going to return None.

if you want to get rid of it in your code

instead of

   `print "You still owe: " + str(new_balance)`

put 

    `return "You still owe: " + str(new_balance)`

most iterpreters if they see None they just wont output anything.

Comment: @user2368136: Let me try one more explanation: Outside of programming, a "function" is something that takes some values and gives you another value. So, in many programming languages (including Python), every function returns a value, by definition. `None` is sort the general "I need a value, but don't have anything useful" value in Python, so that's what Python fills in if you don't tell it what you want your function to return.

Answer (score 0):

This was mentioned in the comments to @abarnert's post, but I'm putting it in answer form so that it's more visible.

What you want is for your function to return the string, and then the interpreter will spit that string back out at you:

```
def make_payment(payment, balance): 
    new_balance2 = balance - payment
    new_balance = add_monthly_interest(new_balance2)
    return "You still owe: " + str(new_balance) # <-- Note the return

# Now we change how we call this
print make_payment(100,bill)

# An alternative to the above
message = make_payment(100,bill)
print message
```

Now, the only thing that will be shown on the command line will be the message.

**NOTE**

As you had written the code previously (omitting the `return` statement) python was assuming that you had written your function as:

```
def make_payment(payment, balance): 
    new_balance2 = balance - payment
    new_balance = add_monthly_interest(new_balance2)
    print "You still owe: " + str(new_balance)
    return None # <-- Python added this for you
```

All functions must return a value, and since you did not include the `return` statement python added one for you.  Since it appears your interactive shell was printing to the screen *all* values returned by python functions, you were seeing the `None` after the function was called.